# how to achive Visual Code intellisense in web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, performance, visual-studio-code

I'm react developer for 2 months. My aim is to build my own website like GitHub for this of course I need some kind of IDE like `VS code` where I can upload my code. I recently learned about `VS Code Intellisense` but I did not find some helpful content. I don't how it works but what I learned is, `VS Code` keeps track of changes in the file intelligent code completion uses an automatically generated in-memory database of classes, variable names, and other constructs that give computer code defines or references. As I mentioned earlier I want to build my own IDE like `VS Code` i end up with a simple approach but it's not efficient. Please have a look at my approach and then suggest me better approach.

```
 // list of some keyword
 const listOfKeyWords = {
    'var' , 'const' , 'let' , 'for' , 'if' , 'else' // ...
 }
 
 const [ code , SetCode ] = useState('') // grabs value from DOM input tag
 const [ filterCodeState , SetFilterCodeState ] = useState('')
 
 // Filter Code
 function FilterCode ( ) {
    let filterCode = ''
    var stack = new Stack

    code.forEach ( (word , idx) => {
       if(word === ' '){
          let str = ''

          while(!stack.empty())
            str.push (stack.top())

          if(listOfKeyWords.indexOf(str) != -1) // string is keyWord add color to it
             filterCode += `<p className = 'text-info'>${str}</p>`
          else filterCode += str
       }

       stack.push(word)
       SetFilterCode(SetFilterCode)
   })
 }

  return ( <>
      { SetFilterCodeState }
     </>
  )
```

I know there are lots to do but this is simple code. of course, it will take too much performance cost. How I can make something like this and also manage performance.

Please answer the following questions :

- Is there any plug-in I can use directly?
- How color of ide work is they change color using HTML and CSS?
- How I can manage the database for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trying to build your own web-based IDE with accurate intellisense for a variety of languages (or even just one) from scratch would be a truly herculean task - it would probably take a team of experienced developers months or years. Luckily the editor behind VSCode - Monaco - is open-source and could be integrated into any web-based project. You can learn more about Monaco [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/). There's a playground that shows you some of the ways it can be configured. The [README on github](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor#readme) has instructions about how to get started integrating it into your project.

Comment: what about if i just want to render code with highlighted syntax on the webpage?

Comment: Monaco will do syntax highlighting, but if you don't need editing or autocomplete -- just read-only syntax highlighting, it might be easier to use a library like [prism](https://prismjs.com/) or [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

Comment: one last question can I use this in react or can you show some react code examples?

Comment: Sure - [here is an example of how to use monaco in react](https://codesandbox.io/s/u0fyv), and the same thing for [prism](https://github.com/catchsrinivas/PrismJS-Tutorial/blob/main/src/components/Code.js) and the [highlight-react package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight), which wraps highlight.js for easy use within react.

Comment: thanks man.please consider up vote my question so it can help other people who are dreaming to make their own ide in web

Comment: Thats still only just a text editor with limited language support. What If I want to have intellisense on the level of clangd in that?